# struts2 : FilterDispatcher <<< is deprecated Please use the new filters

Tags: java, struts2

In struts2 I am getting the bellow error, I know how to fix it just to get rid of the warning which is described in this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226542/filterdispatcher-is-deprecated-what-is-the-replacement-for-filterdispatcher).

```
FilterDispatcher <<< is deprecated! Please use the new filters!
```

My problem is, in my existing code I have a custom dispatcher. It works like below

```
public class TestFilterDispatcher extends FilterDispatcher {
    @Override
    protected Dispatcher createDispatcher(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
        Map params = new HashMap();
        for (Enumeration e = filterConfig.getInitParameterNames(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
            String name = (String) e.nextElement();
            String value = filterConfig.getInitParameter(name);
            params.put(name, value);
        }
        return new TestDispatcher(filterConfig.getServletContext(), params);
    }
}
```

and then the TestDispacher is handling the error like below. Not sure how I will do this same using the new org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.

```
public class TestDispatcher extends Dispatcher {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestDispatcher.class);

    public TestDispatcher(ServletContext servletContext, Map<String, String> initParams) {
        super(servletContext, initParams);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendError(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ServletContext ctx, int code,
            Exception e) {
            // have handled some error related problems here
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a better solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/16875911/573032

Comment: @RomanC Thank you ! Question, Not sure how to write logic like if error 500 do something, if error 400 do something, with the above url example.

Comment: There were similar questions & [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27001380/573032).